# How to use Priority API?

Tags: priority-web-sdk

I'm trying to create a simple application that reminds me of two weeks before I was supposed to get a delivery. My data is store in a Priority database and I'm looking for a way to read it using code (prefer in Python).
I read about Priority REST API and tested it with the examples that are in the site(https://prioritysoftware.github.io/restapi/request/). it seems like this is the way to do it but I see that it requires a URL to the Priority account and I don't know what is my URL because I use the desktop app.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is using the API is the best way?
2. how do I find the URL to my account?

In addition I would be happy for further help regarding my idea for a program reminiscent of two weeks before receiving a delivery (examples, tips, ways to implement and so on).

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

- In order to use Priority API you need to install its application server.
   [More information can be found here.](https://cdn.priority-software.com/docs/Priority_OData_API.pdf)

- If you are working locally you can access **carefully** directly to your SQL server and look for your data.
- Priority has built-in functionality to send email reminders (BPM rules)